# Change language in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

I have a VM with Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server Management Studio on it, but the menu UI is all in German. I have the OS settings to English and United States for language, region settings, etc. When I go to Tools > Options > International in SQL server, the only option is German. Any ideas?

Comment: My copy of Management Studio (which is the 17.x branch that you [download separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)) has a [Get additional languages](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=558810&clcid=0x409) link in that dialog box, which goes to the Visual Studio 2015 language pack. The 2012 Management Studio uses the VS 2010 shell, so you could try [the language pack for that](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27110) (or just upgrade Management Studio, it's backwards compatible).

Answer (score 0):

Thats from the SQL Server Installed. The only way is to reinstall with the language version you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed German version of Management Studio, uninstall and install English version

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can't install a language pack or anything? You have to uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell (en-US) and install it. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/